# How to make the sphere use cube map in threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures

[image: example]

For example, in the case of level 2, the texture of one face of a cube is composed of 16 separate images.
How should I render 96(6x16) or more images onto a sphere?
I used `cubeTexture` to merge the image of level 1, but there was an error when I rendered it to the sphere.

##### An Error

[image: a error]

##### Demo

[image: demo]

```
const cubeLoader = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader();
cubeLoader.setPath('/texture/');

const skybox = cubeLoader.load([
    '/skybox/sky_pos_x.png', '/skybox/sky_neg_x.png',
    '/skybox/sky_pos_y.png', '/skybox/sky_neg_y.png',
    '/skybox/sky_pos_z.png', '/skybox/sky_neg_z.png'
]);
scene.background = skybox;
const earthGeo = new THREE.SphereGeometry(5, 640, 320);
// earthMaterial.shadowSide=THREE.DoubleSide;
const earthMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial({
    envMap: cubeLoader.load([
        '/moon/surface_diff_pos_x.png', '/moon/surface_diff_neg_x.png',
        '/moon/surface_diff_pos_y.png', '/moon/surface_diff_neg_y.png',
        '/moon/surface_diff_pos_z.png', '/moon/surface_diff_neg_z.png'
    ]),
    bumpMap: cubeLoader.load([
        '/moon/surface_bump_pos_x.png', '/moon/surface_bump_neg_x.png',
        '/moon/surface_bump_pos_y.png', '/moon/surface_bump_neg_y.png',
        '/moon/surface_bump_pos_z.png', '/moon/surface_bump_neg_z.png'
    ]),
    normalMap: cubeLoader.load([
        '/moon/surface_norm_pos_x.png', '/moon/surface_norm_neg_x.png',
        '/moon/surface_norm_pos_y.png', '/moon/surface_norm_neg_y.png',
        '/moon/surface_norm_pos_z.png', '/moon/surface_norm_neg_z.png'
    ])
});
console.log(earthMaterial);
const earth = new THREE.Mesh(earthGeo, earthMaterial);
```

However, there is no error when applying texture to envMap or skyBox to map

Comment: please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and share your demo code as a code-block instead of an image! [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: thanks,this is my first time to ask a questions on StackOverflow.